# how to establish what is the parent of a native widget gtk3

Tags: python-2.7, gtk3

Hi I am looking for method to define what the parent of a native widget is in gtk3

for example in Python:

```
def herit_of( widget):
```

and for `Gtk.image`

```
print herit_of(Gtk.image)
>>> Gtk.Misc
```

[Here's a link](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Misc.html#gtk-misc-methods).

Comment: my target to obtain list like that list_method = set(herit_of(Gtk.image))-set(Gtk.image)

Comment: nobody has a small idea ????

Answer (score 1):

If one want to know what are the ancestors of a class, there is the `__mro__` tuple.

Example:

```
class Foo(object):
     pass

class Bar(Foo):
     pass

 print(Foo.__mro__)
 bar = Bar()
 print(bar.__class__.__mro__)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok for me.

the test code follow for how to

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Bar(Gtk.Window):
    pass


bar = Bar()
info= bar.__class__.__mro__
for element in info:
    print element
```

the result is

```
class '__main__.Bar'

class 'gi.overrides.Gtk.Window'

class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Window'

class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Bin'

class 'gi.overrides.Gtk.Container'

class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Container'

class 'gi.overrides.Gtk.Widget'

class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Widget'

class 'gi.repository.GObject.InitiallyUnowned'

class 'gi.overrides.GObject.Object'

class 'gi.repository.GObject.Object'

type 'gi._gobject.GObject'

class 'gi.repository.Atk.ImplementorIface'

class 'gi.repository.Gtk.Buildable'

type 'gobject.GInterface'

type 'object'
```

with this data I should build a tree of dependance 
very cool